# BI Publisher logic to test for existence within a grouping

Tags: peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I am working with a PeopleSoft BI Publisher RTF template and will be working with an XML document that has multiple rows, similar to below:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<query numrows="3" queryname="GH3_HRS_OFFER_DS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
<row rownumber="1">
<A.ERNCD/>
<A.EARNS_AMT>0</A.EARNS_AMT>
<A.OFFER_COMPONENT><![CDATA[BASSAL]]></A.OFFER_COMPONENT>
</row>
<row rownumber="2">
<A.ERNCD/>
<A.EARNS_AMT>0</A.EARNS_AMT>
<A.OFFER_COMPONENT><![CDATA[PROB]]></A.OFFER_COMPONENT>
</row>
<row rownumber="3">
<A.ERNCD/>
<A.EARNS_AMT>0</A.EARNS_AMT>
<A.OFFER_COMPONENT><![CDATA[SIGNON]]></A.OFFER_COMPONENT>
</row>
</query>
```

What I need to do is display the 1st paragraph if the data has a row with `OFFER_COMPONENT = 'PROB'` and I think this is working ok as-is for the first paragraph.

However I want this to function so that either the 1st paragraph above displays, **or** the 2nd paragraph (`<?if@inlines:A.OFFER_COMPONENT<>'PROB'?>`) displays, but not both.

I don't think the way I have the 2nd paragraph coded `<?if@inlines:A.OFFER_COMPONENT<>'PROB'?>`) will prevent this paragraph from displaying, as once it encounters a row with a value other than `'PROB'` it will display this paragraph also. I want to be able to essentially test for the existence within a group (multiple rows) whether the field `A.OFFER_COMPONENT ='PROB'`. If one of the rows for this field does contain 'PROB' then I do **NOT** want the 2nd paragraph to display.

I looked online and did not readily see a way of checking for the existence of a value of a field on multiple rows, so if anyone knows a way of doing this I would appreciated it. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on this are appreciated. I am thinking there has to be a way to evaluate an element across multiple rows...

Answer (score 0):

So you are able to check if the first paragraph needs to be printed. Nice. Now just after you print that first paragraph, you could set a global variable to true. Check `xdoxslt:set_variable`. 
Now you only need to print the second paragraph if the value of this global variable is false.

Comment: that is an interesting idea! What would be the syntax for both setting the variable and then checking for it?

Comment: Search xdoxslt:set_variable function.

Answer (score 0):

First, for the paragraph selection, use `<?if@inlines:A.OFFER_COMPONENT='PROB'?>` for the first paragraph, and `<?if@inlines:A.OFFER_COMPONENT<>'PROB'?>` for the second paragraph. Making sure to end each if condition with an end-if

Second, I see is that you are using a lot of `for-each` statements for sections that will not, or should not, contain multiple rows. For example, you have this:

...only will be $**for-each**0.00**end** per hour,...

for-each is for multiple records. You are already in the `row` level, so there's no need to go into the `row` again with a `for-each`. Otherwise, if you need to navigate the XML Path, just use `row/A.OFFER_AMT`.

`for-each` should be used for something like an invoice or packing list lines where you want to display the same thing multiple times, like for all of the items on the invoice or packing list.